# Giving Tolkien Architecture a Reality Check: Rivendell

Tags: internal-consistency, construction, architecture

[image]

Rivendell, or Imladris in its original Elvish tongue, is the realm of Elrond Half-Elven that was first described in *The Hobbit* and later expanded upon in *The Lord of the Rings*.

To convey the elegance of the elves, Alan Lee created Rivendell for the movies using art nouveau, which isn't often used in architecture.  It's more associated with the artwork done by French painters at the turn of the 20th century, [though its origins actually started a bit earlier.](https://www.artsy.net/article/artsy-editorial-art-nouveau)

Using art nouveau as architecture seems solely decorative and not used for practical uses, like defense.  Then again, [it could be both decorative and useful, like Gothic architecture.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/49178/could-rome-have-invented-gothic-architecture)

So if Rivendell ever were to exist in real life, would art nouveau architecture be too decorative to use in a city, or would it be both ornate and practical?  If the latter is possible, then how?

Comment: The picture has NOTHING to do with Tolkien.  There are paintings of Rivendell by Tolkien: http://scv.bu.edu/~aarondf/Rivimages/rivjrrt2.jpg and http://scv.bu.edu/~aarondf/Rivimages/rivjrrt1.jpg  No similarity at all - and Tolkien's version is far more practical.  See for instance the problems with Wright's "Fallingwater": http://scv.bu.edu/~aarondf/Rivimages/rivjrrt1.jpg

Comment: As for a Rivendell in real life, I always thought it would look rather like the Ahwahnee Hotel in Yosemite.

Comment: @jamesqf Those drawings contain almost no architectural detail and geologists might take issue with the inconsistency in rock faces, undermining (pun?) any merit they have as "actual" documentation.

Comment: How is this "opinion-based"?

Comment: @rek: They may not contain much detail, but anything that claims to be Tolkien ought to be consistent with the information, written or drawn, which Tolkien supplied.  Not something dreamed up by some "evileyed-black- handed- bowlegged-flinthearted-clawfingered-foulbellied- bloodthirsty, morimaitesincahonda, hoom, well, since you are hasty folk and their full name is as long as years of torment". that vermin of a movie director.

Comment: @jamesqf  You have a REAL issue with the movies, don't you? Because that is what the series is primarily based upon.

Comment: @JohnWDailey: Of course I have an issue, just as I'd have issues with anyone who completely trashes any work of art.  As for "series", I'm not sure what you're referring to.  However, if you use Tolkien in your title, you  ought to stick to Tolkien.  Otherwise you might as well add some Star Wars or Marvel Comics stuff - both have about as much relationship to Tolkien.

Comment: @jamesqf  You can't convert 100% of a book into a movie.  It's just not possible.

Answer (score 7):

## Art Nouveau is practical

[Art Nouveau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_Nouveau#Architecture) isn't just practical, it was one of the [primary styles](https://www.architecturaldigest.com/gallery/the-most-beautiful-art-nouveau-buildings-around-the-world) that new buildings were built in in the 1890-1910 time frame. Plenty of [fin-de-siecle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fin_de_si%C3%A8cle) buildings were made in this style, but few of them were offical government buildings. Instead it dominated as a style for apartments, which are eminently practical and livable.

[Riga, Latvia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riga) in particular has a wide variety of [such buildings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Street,_Riga) many designed by [Mikhail Eisenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Eisenstein). So there are examples of whole neighborhoods with such buildings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

J.R.R. Tolkien actually did draw several drawings of the valley of Rivendell.

Here is a link to one:

http://askmiddlearth.tumblr.com/post/67803020886/tolkiens-scenery-artwork[1](http://askmiddlearth.tumblr.com/post/67803020886/tolkiens-scenery-artwork)

Elrond's house is drawn very small and thus is probably greatly oversimplified.  From what we see of it there is little indication that if resembles the structures in the movies very much.

The art nouveau influenced style of the buildings in the Peter Jackson movies seems like a good and practical style for a building in the tropics.  But as I remember them from the movies the buildings are too open to be practical in temperate regions such as Rivendell.

Kingledion's answer may say that art nouveau is practical, but in temperate regions all practical buildings, including art nouveau style buildings, are much more enclosed for temperature control than the open buildings in the movie version of Rivendell.

Elves may be able to endure temperature extremes much better than humans, but since Elrond often has many non elf guests, it would be inhospitable for him to not provide guest quarters more suited for temperature control.  Thus I consider  Rivendell in the movies impractical for its climate.

Comment: As a perhaps only slightly related comment to this off topic answer, in my first reading of The Hobbit (way before the recent movies), I pictured Rivendale as simply a large house up against a cliff not too far off a trail Thorin and Co were hiking along.